# PHP - GET url ignoring linebreaks

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Okay, so here's my problem.

I have "page1.php", with following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>

<textarea id="note-textarea"></textarea>

<script>
    $( "#note-textarea" ).keyup( function() {
            $( "#output_div" ).html( $( this ).val() );


    setTimeout(function () {
            var xmlhttp;
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }else{
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("XMLHTTP");
            }


            xmlhttp.open("GET", "/upload-note?note="+$('#note-textarea').val(), true);
            xmlhttp.send(null);
        }, 1000);

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And "upload-note.php", which should upload the content of the textarea from "page1.php", to a MySQL database. For demonstration-purpose, let's just say, that it's going to echo the content of the textfield instead.

```
<?php
    echo($_GET['note']);
?>
```

Now this setup works actually just fine, BUT it's ignoring linebreaks. Any suggestions on how to handle these?

Comment: Why don't you use `$.ajax` post-requests instead? It's a lot easier, and also don't send a whole textarea in your URL..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser ignores linebreaks (`\n`) in HTML documents. You have to change them with `<br>` tags like so..

```
echo nl2br($_GET['note']);
```

---

Change to POST instead of GET

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "/upload-note", true);
xmlhttp.send("note="+$('#note-textarea').val());
```

...

```
echo nl2br($_POST['note']);
```

Comment: Hmm, thank's for you'r suggestion, but it doesn't seems to work. The url is like this: /upload-note?note=This%20is%20a%20testlinebreak, and between the words "test" and "linebreak", there should be a linebreak.

Comment: Using GET will ignore the linebreaks. You need to use POST.

Comment: @user3276657 - see my edit. if this helps, please hit the checkmark :)

Comment: Well, you might be right, that I need POST, in order to get the linebreaks. Thanks for you'r support! :)